# Trouble getting google map to update location through geocoding a users search

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to have my map update with the users input in the mapSearch box when they hit submit but I'm missing something that's not connecting the submit onclick function with the latlng variable.

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng =new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397,150.644);

   var mapProp = {
    center: latlng, 
    }
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

  };

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('mapsearch'));

google.maps.event.addDomListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function(){

  var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var i, place;

  for (i=0; place=places[i]; i++){

    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);

  }
});


$( "#Submit" ).click(function codeAddress(){
  var address = document.getElementById("mapsearch").value;
  geocoder.geocode( {'mapsearch': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results [0].geometry.location
      });

    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: ` InvalidValueError: unknown property mapsearch` on this line: ` geocoder.geocode( {'mapsearch': address},` (that should be 'address')

Comment: I tried to shorten it to just the parts I thought were the issue, but it looks like that was a rookie mistake:here's the full code

Answer (score 0):

I get a javascript error with the posted code: `InvalidValueError: unknown property mapsearch` on this line: `geocoder.geocode( {'mapsearch': address},` (that should be 'address'):

```
$("#Submit").click(function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById("mapsearch").value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  },
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

  var mapProp = {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 3
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);



  $("#Submit").click(function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("mapsearch").value;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
      },
      function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
          });

        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="Submit" type="button" value="submit" />
<input id="mapsearch" value="New York, NY" />
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```